# How can i have an access to style object in another function

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can i have an access to style object in another function. I've got this part

```
...
onOk: function() {

          var style = new CKEDITOR.style({
            element: 'p',
            styles: {
              //some styles
            },
            spaceFlag: 'superFlag'
          });
          editor.applyStyle( style );
    },
    onShow: function(){
    // i want to get here spaceFlag
 }
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you do not have one function which calls the other. Instead, they are both siblings who are children of the parent context. So define your styles in the parent context:

```
var styleOptions = {
        element: 'p',
        styles: {
          //some styles
        },
        spaceFlag: 'superFlag'
    }, onOk: function() {
        var style = new CKEDITOR.style(styleOptions);
        editor.applyStyle( style );
    },
    onShow: function(){
        // i want to get here spaceFlag
        styleOptions.spaceFlag
    },
...
```

Here's a separate snippet you can run out-of-the-box:

```js
    function logMe() {
        var styleOptions = {
            element: 'p',
            styles: {
              //some styles
            },
            spaceFlag: 'superFlag'
        };
        console.log(styleOptions.spaceFlag);
    }
    logMe();
```

Comment: i was thinking about it, but the styles are dynamically goes with each `ok` button clicking. So getting this object out of `onOk` is not an option(

Comment: Doesn't matter. It should still work because the local function like onOk will change the value of the higher context variable, and the next function can access that. If this doesn't work for you please add more code for me to see and I'll fix it. I use this pattern all the time.

Comment: i think i'll just add an attribute to an element so i could get an access to it while edit. Because all styles goes from dialog window and values that i'm setting is bind to dialog object so i could not place object up. in any case you forced me to think better )